# Can SQL Server 2005 Use TLS 1.2 for Web Apps?

Tags: ssl, windows-server-2003, sql, sql-server-2005

Hoping for some help as this is a bit new to me.

We have a legacy app running ASP with a separate SQL Server 2005 running on Server 2003 instance. I'd like to required TLS 1.2 for all web app traffic, but when I disable TLS 1.0, the app breaks. It seems to indicate that the SQL 2005/Server 2003 does not support TLS 1.2, is that correct? If so, is there a workaround?

Answer (score 1):

its not possible, TLS 1.2 is support only SQL 2008 or higher

Comment: Welcome to ServerFault.  It'd be a better answer if you cited something authoritative like https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3135244/tls-1-2-support-for-microsoft-sql-server

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kaushal/2011/10/02/support-for-ssltls-protocols-on-windows/

Comment: Is that something that should be part of the answer?  If so, please edit the answer.  It is easy for someone to miss information in the comments.